# In fluentd, does drop_oldest_chunk reset retry_wait?

Tags: fluentd

In fluentd, regarding retry_limit, disable_retry_limit http://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/output-plugin-overview:

> If the limit is reached, buffered data is discarded and the retry interval is reset to its initial value (retry_wait).

In my setup I have the following configuration for output:

```
buffer_queue_limit 200
buffer_chunk_limit 1m
flush_interval 3s
buffer_queue_full_action drop_oldest_chunk
max_retry_wait 1h
disable_retry_limit true
```

So we will keep retrying to output from buffer, with a max_retry_wait of 1 hour, untill the buffer queue is full, in which case it will drop the oldest chunk and move onto the next one.

With the disable_retry_limit set to true, this means we drop the oldest chunk only when the buffer queue is full, `buffer_queue_full_action drop_oldest_chunk`.

My question is, when this buffer queue drops the oldest chunk, is the retry_wait(default 1s, incrementing with each try) reset to it's initial value for the next chunk in the queue due to be outputted (giving same behavior as when retry_limit is reached)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on local machine, fluent-d does not reset the retry_wait to its initial value when a chunk is dropped.